# How to unprotect ASP.NET FormAuthentication cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, asp.net-authentication

Our asp.net website is using FormAuthentication. I want to decrpty the authentication cookie. Here is the code.

```
        string ticket = Request.Cookies[".ASPXAUTH_xxx"].Value.ToString();
        // Format Cookie to be converted
        ticket = ticket.Replace('-', '+').Replace('_', '/');
        var padding = 3 - ((ticket.Length + 3) % 4);
        if (padding != 0)
            ticket = ticket + new string('=', padding);
        var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(ticket);

        // Decrypt
        bytes = System.Web.Security.MachineKey.Unprotect(bytes,
            "Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware",
            "ApplicationCookie", "v1");
```

It always throws out `System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException`. I guess some parameters of System.Web.Security.MachineKey.Unprotect is wrong. Our project is old asp.net webform website, and is not using Owin. So I guess `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware` is not appliable here.

What are the correct parameters to unprotect the data?